# Unable to connect to SQL Server database exception on Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I get

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database

exception on line

```
isAdmin = Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")
```

detailed inner exception is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I am using Asp.net MVC identity. And I am using EF with data first approach. My `web.config` connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835;Integrated Security=True"  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Entities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835.mdf;initial catalog=aspnet-Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject-20141215093835;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <!-- others -->
</appSettings>
```

To initiallize simple membership, I wrote following class in `Global.asax.cs`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Something is wrong", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look like you are using **Simple Membership Provider** instead of new **ASP.Net Identity**.

Comment: I am using `ASP.Net Identity` but to tackle this exception I found the solutions that used `Simple Membership Provider`. I didn't knew much about `Simple Membership Provider` and I don't want to use it. How can I tackle this exception with `ASP.Net Identity`